# Oracle LAG Without a Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select the previous salary and current for calculating a percentage.

I'm attempting to use the Oracle Analytical function LAG which is processed only before the final order by clause. Because the LAG function is not ran until after the where clause, if I include my where clause to narrow down just one employee, it works flawlessly however when including all employees it returns whatever row is above it.

Has anyone faced this before?

**Working (returns in order with proper amounts):**

```
select
  employee,
  payrate,
  lag(payrate) over (order by effectdate) as prevrow
from
  payratetable;
where employee = 1234;
```

**Not Working (returns with random rates from other employees):**

```
select
  employee,
  payrate,
  lag(payrate) over (order by effectdate) as prevrow
from
  payratetable;
```

Comment: Use `partition by employee`

Comment: That did it. Thank you! Time to research why. :)

Comment: @0perator - **Bravo** for the absolutely right reaction. "Time to research why" - if only more people had this great instinct. It is indeed time to research why; you will learn something super great about analytic functions, their ability to partition data into separate groups and to work on each group in isolation, as if there were no other groups to work on at the same time. An exceptionally useful feature of (almost?) all analytic functions, not just LAG.

Comment: Bravo +1.  @0perator, if you want to learn about Analytics, I did a 30 video series on it.  LAG get covered about half way through.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvZ4SmKtazs&list=PLJMaoEWvHwFJDyhMLCkNSSUQWw9waFkIj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer was accomplished with help from those in the comments.

Adding the partition by in the over clause solved this problem by forcing GROUPING or **PARTITIONING** to the employee field of the records.

```
select
  employee,
  payrate,
  lag(payrate) over (partition by employee order by effectdate) as prevrow
from
  payratetable;
```